# FileUpload file cleared after uploading it with ftp

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, ftp

I'm having trouble processing a uploaded file after it has been uploaded with ftp.

The file the user uploads contains xml. I have to save this file to disk but I'm not able to write this file directly to disk so I use ftp to save it. After it is saved it needs to be processed to save it contents in a database. The XmlReader fails with the error "No root element detected". After some debugging I came to the conclusion the file is empty.

I tried to copy the file (where xsdUpload is the file uploaded by the user):

```
FileUpload test = new FileUpload();
test = xsdUpload;
```

But I'm not really shure if this also copys the file in memory.

The ftp upload function is as followed:

```
    public string uploadXsd(string fileName, FileUpload xsd)
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url + '/' + fileName);

        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

        StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(xsd.FileContent);
        byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
        sourceStream.Close();
        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        response.Close();
        return url + '/' + fileName;
    }
```

This function works fine. I can see the file in the directory where it supposed to be.

To process the file I use:

```
 XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xsdUploaded.FileContent);

 while (reader.Read())
 {
      if (reader.Name != "")
      {
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that FileContent property is a **Stream class instance** and you should Seek it to the beginning before the second reading, i.e.

```
xsdUploaded.FileContent.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xsdUploaded.FileContent);
```

I am not sure, hope this helps.

Best regards.

Comment: I've checked the length of the file with xsdUploaded.FileContent.Lenght and the return value whas 0 but I'll try it out